# Cant redirect to url

Tags: angularjs

I have this code :

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $location, userModel){
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current){
    if ($location.path() == '/' && userModel.getAuthStatus()) {
        console.log(userModel.getStartUrl());
        $location.path(userModel.getStartUrl());
    };
```

when i load page site/#/ user will redirected to startUrl, but if load site/ without # user will not rederected, but            `console.log(userModel.getStartUrl());` will executed

```
userModel.getAuthStatus() means that user is logged
```

Comment: Can you show us the output of `console.log(userModel.getStartUrl());`?

Comment: userModel.getStartUrl = function(){
  if (userModel.getUserRole() == 'admin')
  {
   return '/users';
  }
  else
  {
   return '/proposals';
  }
 };

Comment: add a console log for `userModel.getAuthStatus()`